SystemTrayMenu for Linux / Ubuntu
i recently moved to Ubuntu 23.10 from Windows and use gnome Nutilus 45r.
In windows I had a "click start" tool, or lets call it "link list" where all the frequent files and apps I use are colleced.
Up to Windows 10 "toolbars" could be added to the taskbar, simply by opening a folder as toolbar. The folder contained all the links to the files and programs. One click on the taskbar icon to open a list of the folder content, next click to open the file/program.
In Windows 11 MS deactivated the toolbar feature (and some tweaks are needed to have them again), however, an awesome app called SystemTrayMenu was created by German coders.
SystemTrayMenu example screenshot
The picture shows an example of SystemTray Menu. It is simple to add links to files / programs as needed and again two clicks to start.
For ubuntu / linux I have not found such a feature. Is this really true? I thought this is a standard app to be downloaded, but none found so far.
So again, i would like to have a icon in the taskbar - once clicked a list of freely configurable links to files/folders/programs is shown, and clicking on one shall open it.
Any idea anyone?
I have now added a "bookmark" in gnome, but must first start gnome, which is an additional click.
Any other ideas, maybe any alternative linklist to files/folders/programs which can be started with a click on a shortcut in the taskbar?
A thread that had same question but to no avail is here: How do I pin my favorite folders in Ubuntu dock like in Windows?
Thanks for hints!

thx, updated the post accordingly. I use stock/standard ubuntu 23.10 with gnome 45rc.

hmm that seems more difficult than I expected. I can't find a dock or extension for gnome 45.  hopefully someone else comes around ;)

Are you looking for a dock like plank, where you can pin folders and programs?

I have Dash to panel and Arc menu installed , but I run 22.04, do not know if they are available on 23.10.

Archisman Panigrahi - sadly plank is not working on ubuntu23.10. "Only X11 environments are supported" it says.

@amar - Dash to panel i have too, but it does not allow to pin folders. Arc Menu I tried but also did not find out how to pin folders and files ....

@Karina, in Arc Menu you can add files and folders,go to properties of Arc menu, menu, Brisk Layout Tweaks, Add custom shortcuts, you have to specify program and the destination Like: gedit /home/yourname/yourfile or nautilus /home/yourname/Desktop, look at all of the settings, you can also remove the things you do not want.

You have to choose Brisk in Menu Layout, before you can see Brisk Layout Tweaks.

thanks guys, very helpful, i found the custom shortcuts and can pimp my menu now. excellent!

thanks again, i tested arcmenu and via eclipse / menulibre one can add custom shortcuts which then can be organized in ArcMenu. So far so fine.

For ArcMenu - can someone help with how to sort pinned aps?  I use the Plasma menu theme, and it has "pinned aps" which is super to get the aps/shortcuts i use frequently on one page/menu. But i fail to get the apps sorted by name. They are shown as fifo - first pinned, first shown. I tried to "Save" the settings file, and edited the settings file by sorting the entries for the pinned aps by hand, then loaded the settings file - but to no avail, the sorting is still the same (not sure if saving and loading works).

I found the answer on how to sort the "Arc pinned aps" with the Plasma theme - just drag the app and move it in the required position, a bit tedious for long lists, however, at least that allows for manual sorting.

Just to post some status - I still have not found any extension / tool for Linux that can handle menus so efficient and seamless as SystemTrayMenu (https://github.com/Hofknecht/SystemTrayMenu) does on windows.
System Tray Menu are working on a linux version, but i dont think thats very intense.
That's why I use ArcMenu on Ubuntu now. But setting this bitch up with possibly hundreds of links and desktop items is a tedious endeavour. So I am still happy to hear about possible other solutions.
